# How to align bones so their rotations are the same?

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm fairly new to Blender and am having some problems with skeletons/armatures, specifically aligning fingers on a hand so they are rotated facing the same way. I can't find an option to do it in edit mode and it's making my end product rotate weirdly, mainly the thumb.

So say, I have a bone like this:

[image]

If I wanna align a bone in 3DS Max I press Alt-A which brings up an option to "Align" anything to anything, I can select transformations, rotations and scale, copying from the object I select afterwards. Here's an example:

[image]
[image]

So if I select all the transformations, rotations and scales, it'll place it in the exact same location, rotated in the exact same way and scaled the exact same way, but maybe I just want to align their rotations so their axes are the same, I can do that easily by just ticking the appropriate boxes. This is great for aligning bones so that they're all on the same axis.

Here, I just ticked the rotations and you can see the rotation data has been copied to the bone:

[image]

So I wanna have fingers all aligned perfectly as they tend to be in real life, in Max I just do that method I just said and I can align the finger bones so that their axes are lined up.

In Blender I can't seem to do this, I just have to guess and hope that I've placed things so they're rotated the same. Is there some way to align the bones like I just showed in those images with Blender? Or am I stuck guessing and hoping things don't look too bad?

Answer (score 5):

### How to align bones' orientation to reference bone's one.

**Using custom orientation**

1. Select *Transform Pivot Point > Active Element*
2. Select a reference bone
3. Make a custom orientation for the bone (*Transfer Orientation > +icon*)
4. Select other bones and activate the reference bone then
5. Press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys

[image]

### How to align bones' roll values to reference bone's one.

**Using Alt key**

1. Select the bones and activate the reference bone
2. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and make *Transform > Roll* text to be editable then
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

[image]

Comment: This should be accepted answer! Detailed and well explained! Sharp and smart!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bone `Copy Rotation` constraint then `Apply Visual Transform to Pose` then `Apply Pose as Rest Pose`.

[image]
As far as I can remember someone here in BSE had created a script to make this process faster, you may find it with a quick search.

Comment: Can't you use Armature > Bone Roll > Recalculate or SHFT-N then Active Bone in Edit mode to recalculate a bone roll chain?